# Перебор каталогов на предмет нужного файла/директории

Tags: python, файловая-система

Код должен перебрать все папки в Users что бы найти папку пользователя

```
import os

path = 'C:/'
usr = 'Users'

dir = os.listdir(path)

print(dir)

if usr in dir:
    udir = path + usr
    os.chdir(udir)
    usrs = os.listdir(udir)

    usrlen = len(usrs)

    while usrlen != 0:

        i = usrlen - 1
        aus = os.listdir(usrs[i])

        # print(aus)
        if 'Desktop' in aus:
            print('Hello')
            break
        else:
            print('Bye')
            continue
```

При исполнении он просто спамит bye и всё
Если что не написал прошу извинить не так давно начал пользоваться этим сайтом

Comment: Значение `usrlen` не изменяется в цикле.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, вам больше подойдет модуль glob.

```
import glob

#if "Desktop" in glob.glob("Desktop"):
if "Desktop" in glob.glob("*"):
    print("Hello")
else:
    print("Bye")
```

---

`glob.glob(mask)`, mask - маска полного имени файла / директории. Возвращает список подходящих файлов и директорий.

Comment: Благодарю, я даже не знал лб этом модуле